# wordpress additional class to ul and to sub-menu ul

Tags: html, css, wordpress, class, html-lists

I am not an expert with wordpress and did not find any clear solution in other posts (or in google) for my following question:

I created a ***responsive*** general php page with specific classess for the ul, li, submenu-ul and submenu-li to accomodate my responsive design.

I am integrating my website with wordpress and I want to add additional css classess to the main ul and to the submenu-ul.
The current class the main ul item has is: 
The current class in every ul item is:

for example:

```html
<ul id="menu-primary-menu-links" class="menu">
 <li class="menu-item li_1"><a href="web-development.php" >link1</a>
    <ul id="sub-menu">
       <li class="menu-item li_1"><a href="web-development.php" >link3</a>
       </li>
       <li class="menu-item li_1"><a href="web-development.php" >link4</a>
       </li>
    </ul>
 </li>
 <li class="menu-item li_1"><a href="web-development.php" >link2</a>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
       <li class="menu-item li_1"><a href="web-development.php" >link5</a>
       </li>
       <li class="menu-item li_1"><a href="web-development.php" >link6</a>
       </li>
    </ul>
 </li>
</ul>
```

---

I want it to be for example:

```html
    <ul id="menu-primary-menu-links" class="menu nav-list">      { here I added **nav-list** class }
 <li class="menu-item li_1"><a href="web-development.php" >link1</a>
    <ul id="sub-menu block_one_col">      { here I added **block_one_col** class }
       <li class="menu-item li_1"><a href="web-development.php" >link3</a>
       </li>
       <li class="menu-item li_1"><a href="web-development.php" >link4</a>
       </li>
    </ul>
 </li>
 <li class="menu-item li_1"><a href="web-development.php" >link2</a>
    <ul class="sub-menu block_wide_ul">      { here I added **block_wide_ul** class }
       <li class="menu-item li_1"><a href="web-development.php" >link5</a>
       </li>
       <li class="menu-item li_1"><a href="web-development.php" >link6</a>
       </li>
    </ul>
 </li>
</ul>
```

How can I do it?
Please specify where should I add any code you mention.

Many thanks you all guys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To assign the `<ul>` of your navigation menu a class, you will need to define the `items_wrap` value inside your array for the `wp_nav_menu` function like this:

```
<?php wp_nav_menu( array('menu' => '//Your Menu Name', 'container' => '', 'items_wrap' => '<ul  id="menu-primary-menu-links" class="menu nav-list">%3$s</ul>' )); ?>
```

You would already be having the above code inside your `header.php` file to echo the navigation menu on the front-end therefore what you can do is that simply paste the following value inside the array: `'items_wrap' => '<ul  id="menu-primary-menu-links" class="menu nav-list">%3$s</ul>'`.

**jQuery solution to add different classes to different sub-menu `<ul>`'s:**

Since Wordpress only allows a single class/id to be assigned to the sub-menu , you will need to use jQuery to add different classes to different sub-menu `<ul>`'s. Here's the sample code:

```js
$( ".menu-item:first-child ul" ).addClass( "block_one_col" );
$( ".menu-item:nth-child(2) ul" ).addClass( "block_wide_ul" );
```

```css
.block_one_col li a {
  color: yellow;
  }

.block_wide_ul li a {
  color: red;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="menu-primary-menu-links" class="menu nav-list">
 <li class="menu-item li_1"><a href="web-development.php" >link1</a>
    <ul class="sub-menu"> 
       <li class="menu-item li_1"><a href="web-development.php" >link3</a>
       </li>
       <li class="menu-item li_1"><a href="web-development.php" >link4</a>
       </li>
    </ul>
 </li>
 <li class="menu-item li_1"><a href="web-development.php" >link2</a>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
       <li class="menu-item li_1"><a href="web-development.php" >link5</a>
       </li>
       <li class="menu-item li_1"><a href="web-development.php" >link6</a>
       </li>
    </ul>
 </li>
</ul>
```

To target the third, fourth and so on sub-menu `<ul>`'s, you can use the `nth-child` psuedo-selectors like this:

```
$( ".menu-item:nth-child(3) ul" ).addClass( "block_wide_ul_new" );
$( ".menu-item:nth-child(4) ul" ).addClass( "block_wide_ul_new_2" );
.
.
.
$( ".menu-item:nth-child(10) ul" ).addClass( "block_wide_ul_new_10" );
```

Comment: Hi Fahad. I registered the nav in wordpress using "register nav menus" and added the primary nav and footer nav. I need different classess for different ul. I gave an example in the snnippet above. Many thanks

Comment: Can you look into your `header.php` file and see if the code starting with `<?php wp_nav_menu(....); ?>` is inside it?

Comment: The current code is:      <nav>
      <?php 
       $args = array(
        'theme_location' => 'primary',
        
       );
      ?>
      
      <?php wp_nav_menu($args); ?>
     </nav>

Comment: Try replacing the code which you've posted above with this: `<?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'primary', 'container' => '', 'items_wrap' => '<ul id="menu-primary-menu-links" class="menu nav-list">%3$s</ul>' )); ?>`

Comment: it is one step further. it is only adding the id and class to the main ul which I also need to customize. Do you know how can I add different class to different submenu ul items?

Comment: You will need to use jQuery if you want to add different classes to the different sub-menu `<ul>`'s since Wordpress only allows a single class/id to be assigned to the sub-menu `<ul>`. Let me know if you'd like to know the jQuery solution.

Comment: jQuery solution - Yes, Please.

Comment: @hagaishaul I've updated my answer above, please check.

Comment: I have a call to jquery file in my website. How can I call to $( ".menu-item:first-child ul" ).addClass( "block_one_col" );
$( ".menu-item:nth-child(2) ul" ).addClass( "block_wide_ul" ); to run after the </nav> is ending to read by the browser? I do not want to use something like: $(document).ready(function(){}

Comment: You can add the jQuery code before the closing `</body>` tag.

Answer (score 0):

First Wordpress Support Menu by hook You can hook a menu by adding following code in header.php :-

```
<nav class="nav-bar">
<?php wp_nav_menu(array( 'container_class'=>'main-nav','container'=>'nav')); ?>`
</nav>
```

Now You need to register this hook so that its come inside the WordPress admin area for this add following code in function.php file of your theme( if this file don't exist please create it):-

```
<?php
if(function_exists('register_nav_menus')) {
register_nav_menus( array('primary'=>'Header Navigation'));
} ?>
```

Now the thing you want to customize start here
Now you need to Customize the appearance of the menu use following code in style.css(i added my own style you can add your css here and modify to ) :-

```
ol, ul {
list-style: none;
}
.nav-bar {
background-color:rgb(238, 107, 107);
height:40px;
box-shadow:2px 2px 0 blue;
}
.main-nav ul, .main-nav li{
display:inline;
}
.main-nav a {
padding: 0px 20px 0px 20px;
text-decoration:none;
line-height:40px;
display:block;
color:#fff;
font-family:sans-sarif;
}
.main-nav a:hover {
background-color:#F53F63;
}
.main-nav ul ul a {
width:135px;
line-height:35px;
padding:0px 20px;
display:block;
}
.main-nav ul li {
position:relative;
float:left;
}
.main-nav ul ul {
position:absolute;
top:-9999999px;
left:0;
opacity:0;
background:#B21434;
text-align:left;
box-shadow:2px 2px 0 blue;
}
.main-nav ul li:hover > ul {
position:absolute;
top:100%;
opacity:1;
}
```

Please modify css according to your need
Now whatever You add from wordpress admin panel will come show in the menu

Please go to wordpress themeing tutorial for in depth knowledge me myself is newbie in wordpress

Comment: Hi Bhartendra. Thanks for the detailed info but I already did it. What I am not able to do is adding additional css classes to the submenu **ul** items. Thanks